# React JS - Firestore, How to save the UID of an specific collection doc inside the doc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to register the UID of the New Doc that is going to be generated after I create it so far I Only understand how to make sure the AUTH.UID is the same as the UID of a registered user and so on (basically auth user UID matchs doc user register UID).

What I'm struggling with is How to I "copy" or "get" the UID of a DOC that is about to be created and add it on the information of the Document

[image]

So in this picture the doc UID matches not only the outside information but the INSIDE information (if that makes sense) but it also matches my USER UID

[image]

Now let's move on to the issue (Idk if I should go straight to the point or explain, I have plenty of questions for a while but now I find this site exists so I'm sorry if I'm asking a lot).

So each USER can create their own personal collection (I think it was the best way to go to not confuse myself)

[image]

As you can see the user can create "students" in their own collection of data (so it doesn't mix with the others users students) but I'm unable to grab that doc UID.

I have try to use doc.uid or a whole database.doc.uid and stuff like that and even though I don't get an error in the syntax (until it tries to create it) it doesn't work, so since I was unable to figure out the doc I decided to use the user.uid meanwhile until I find a solution (which I haven't) and I'm pretty sure the fix is something very silly but I can't find "specific" information of the issue I'm having only general situations This is the relevant part of the code

```
function CrearEstudiante({user}) {    

    const register = (e) => {
        
            e.preventDefault();
               db.collection('usuarios')
               .doc(user.uid)
               .collection('estudiantes').doc()
               .set({

                name: firstName + " " + lastName,
                school: idType1,
                grade: idType2,
                uid: user.uid

            }).then((r) => {
                history.push("/Inicio")
            })
    }
```

This is what I tried:

- db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes').uid
- doc.uid

and if I try to add "uid" on the top argument of auth
so like this:
db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes').doc(uid).set(

it doesn't like it neither

Any tips are welcome, also I'm NOT using real-time database just the firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the uid of the document to be created, you can do something like this:

```
const register = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const docRef = db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes').doc();
  docRef.set({
    name: firstName + " " + lastName,
    school: idType1,
    grade: idType2,
    uid: docRef.id,
    // docRef.id is the id you want.
  }).then((r) => {
      history.push("/Inicio");
  })
}
```

Comment: What does "await" does because I never have use it before, it generates me an error. I think is because await is from an extension and I don't use extension my bad I should have add that.

Comment: await is used to wait for something to complete before proceeding. But I have re-written my answer to work without await.

Comment: await is not an extension, you are getting an error because you didnt register your function as `async` (asynchronous). With await, the next function won't be called until it is done. So instead of using `then`, you can use await.

Comment: So every time I want to get specific data it is better to save it on other variables ? 
I was quite close I had:
db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes').doc(uid).set(

just needed to remove the uid from the () and put it after the dot

Comment: Yes, you were very close. `.doc()` since I didnt pass any id, tells firebase to create a new reference. Then we set the data to that reference and can get the id with `docRef.id`

Comment: That worked! thank you very much I was close though was just missing a small bit, thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote the answer to make it easier to find. So glad I could help.

Comment: Still a bit new to stack overflow I though just marking the check mark counted as a +1 my bad